# Recursive lookup problem in Puppet and Hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

Puppet agent fails with the following error:

```
    Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: 
    Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Lookup of key 'my.net.hosts.agent01' failed: 
    Recursive lookup detected in [my.net.needs_proxy, my.net.hosts.agent01] on node agent01
```

My Hiera setup is as follows. Node-specific file:

```
# environments/test/data/nodes/agent01.yaml
---
my:
  net:
    host:
      ip_address: "%{lookup('my.net.hosts.agent01')}"
      
    needs_proxy: false
```

and the "subsystem" specific file:

```
# environments/test/data/subsystems/main.yaml
---
my:
  net:
    hosts:
      agent01: "192.168.0.1"
      agent02: "192.168.0.2"
      agent03: "192.168.0.3"

    needs_proxy: false
```

hiera.yaml is the following:

```
# environments/test/hiera.yaml
---
version: 5
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-node data"
    path: "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}.yaml"
  - name: "Per-subsystem data"
    path: "subsystems/%{::subsystem}.yaml"
  - name: "Common and fallback data"
    path: "common.yaml"
```

AFAICT it is correctly set-up and both files above are considered in the hierarchy for node `agent01`.

The expected behaviour is that the lookup interpolation `%{lookup('my.net.hosts.agent01')}` in the node-specific file (agent1.yaml) picks up the value as found in the subsystem-specific file (main.yaml). But that does not happen and the above error is produced.

I can't see any obvious mistake, perhaps I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

(edited to add hiera.yaml)

Comment: What is your merge strategy, and what are your Hiera levels? Both could be answered with your `hiera.yaml` configuration. Also, I assume based on the error message that the `my.net.hosts.agent1` is really `my.net.hosts.agent01` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for spotting agent1 vs agent01, i've corrected that above but the error stays all the same. I've edited the question to add the contents of `hiera.yaml` file, too.

Comment: So just to confirm: you have no merge strategies specified anywhere?

Comment: Not that I know of. So I think it defaults to first found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AFAICT it is correctly set-up and both files above are considered in the hierarchy for node agent01.

You need to appreciate that Hiera is a flat key / value store that happens to support values with structured types.  The key / subkey syntax that you demonstrate using with the `lookup` interpolation function might lead a person to mistake the data model for some kind of tree, but such a view leads to incorrect expectations.

In this case, the Hiera data presented defines two values for key `my`.  **The structure of those values is an altogether secondary consideration.**  You having not overridden the default lookup strategy for that key, you get a priority lookup for *the whole value* of that key.  There are then two issues with your data definition:

1. The highest-priority of those values, which is the only one that matters in this case, does not provide the data that you are trying to retrieve via the `lookup` function.
2. As the diagnostic says, you have a recursive lookup: in order to load the value associated with key `my`, the `lookup` function within requires Hiera to first load the value of key `my`.

You could resolve (1) by specifying `deep` merging for `my`, but I do not expect that to resolve (2).

You need to restructure the data, bearing in mind Hiera's flat(-ish) data model.  It's no particular problem for one of the items to be or contain a lookup table of IP addresses, but that can be referenced only externally or from the values of different items.

Comment: OK, I got it thanks. So what happens is that in order to get the value for key `my`, it loads the whole `my` tree which, in turn, contain a reference to `my` itself. Hence the loop. And, to solve that, I have to flatten my config. It's a pity as I wanted to group all my config under the `my` key for the sake of clarity, but according to what you say, it looks that there's no other way round of that.

Comment: You have summarized this answer accurately, @mmanzato, +/- calling the value of key `my` a tree.  Technically, yes, the data structure can be characterized that way, but so can lots of things. That characterization does not match the semantics very well, however, and that manner of thinking is what got you into trouble in the first place.

Comment: I flattened the data config in my hiera yaml files and the problem went away. Thanks.